# Was told to change the .htacess file form .html to .php so this would work properly

Tags: php, htaccess

My video landing page shows up fine on the computer that the video and landing page where edited on. The  VSL shows up fine on a link sent from my computer but when I go to play the video it goes dark. Also mu button does not work it shows up like a broken link???

How do I handle this issue???

here is my .htaccess presently:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN ShortPixelWebp
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN ShortPixelWebp` and `END ShortPixelWebp` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

# END ShortPixelWebp
```

What should the .htaccess file look like after added the code to it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN ShortPixelWebp
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN ShortPixelWebp` and `END ShortPixelWebp` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

# END ShortPixelWebp

RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1[R=301,NC,L]
```

Is this correct, Please let me know.

Comment: What specifically were you told to "change" in `.htaccess`? And why? The directive you "added" at the end in the 2nd example does not really make sense (and is invalid as posted). However, I can't see what your problem has to do with `.htaccess`?